# Difference between two 3-smooth numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider numbers:

$2^ {i+3}\cdot 3^ {i+5}-2^{i}\cdot 3^{i+2}=N$, for i positive and even.

These numbers divided by $215$ leave a perfect sqaures. The few ones are: $18^2$, $108^2$, $3888^2$,...$\in$ S

Now consider the set:

$18,108,3888,...\in R$, where the elements are "de-squared"...

The natural question is are there infinitely many elements k $\in R$ such (k+1) is prime?

What this question is equivalent to?

Comment: You seem to have skipped $648$ in your sequence. These numbers are just those of the form $2^n3^{n+1}$, where $n=i/2$. The question then is, for which $n$ is $2^n3^{n+1}+1$ a prime. I would guess there to be infinitely many such, but we don't even know if there are infinitely many primes of the form $2^n3^m+1$ where $n,m$ are arbitrary.

Comment: To put it slightly differently, the question is whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $3\times6^n+1$.